# Multiple tasks on the same ecs service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I'm newbie on AWS, and I'm working right now with the aws ECS Service .
I noticed an input that asks how much tasks I want to perform in a particular service.

I wonder what is the use of multiple similar tasks in one service .
To the best of my knowledge if I want to run different tasks on the same ec2 instance I'm supposed to create a service for each of them.

So my question is when and why I should use multiple identical tasks in a particular service ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Your question seems to indicate that you think a service is tied to a single EC2 instance. A service with multiple tasks can span multiple EC2 instances.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do? –

Answer (score 1):

> why I should use multiple identical tasks in a particular service

For **scalability and fault-tolerance**. More tasks in a service can handle more load. Also if a single tasks crashes, you have several others to carry out your workload, which prevents downtime.

Comment: What Marcin said. Think of the ECS service (multi-tasks) pattern just like what you did with a bunch of VMs behind a load balancer back in the days. Same thing (conceptually)